# How do I convert this to an ES module?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I convert this to an ES module?

`` require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client); ``

The whole code looks like this:

```
import { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import * as fs from 'fs';

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
client.commands = new Collection();
client.commandArray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
    const functionFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/functions/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

    for (const file of functionFiles)
        require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}

client.handlerCommands();
client.handlerEvents();
client.login(process.env.token);
```

I wrote `` Import(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`) ``, but how do I pass a client?

I have tried `` Import(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client) `` but it does not work.

Comment: Assuming each file in the pattern `"./src/functions/*.js"` is a valid ES module with a default function export, you can replace the `require` line with `import(\`./functions/${folder}/${file}\`).then(mod => mod.default(client))`, but there's no synchronous dynamic import equivalent of `require`.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what kind of files are inside the subdirectory. (CommonJS or ESModules).

When you call `import()` on a commonjs file, the value from `module.exports` is available under `module.default` as soon as the promise from import is resolved. This also works for `exports default statements`.

This will work for commonjs files and esmodule files that use `exports default function() {}`:

```js
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
    const functionFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/functions/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

    for (const file of functionFiles)
        (await import(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)).default(client);
}
```

If all files inside the subdirs are commonjs files, you can also [create a require-function](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename) inside the ESModule that loads the files as before:

```js
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

##### Just a note:

You should change the file extensions to `.cjs` for commonjs and `.mjs` esmodules.